# Filtering dataframe spark scala for dates greater than current time

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame in spark 1.6 that I would like to select all rows greater than the current time. I am filtering on "time_occurred" column with this type of format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS". I was wondering what the best way is to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way would be casting the field to **`timestamp`** type by using **`Regexp_replace`** function to replace `'T'`.

Then by using **`current_timestamp`** function we can filter out data in the dataframe.

**`Example:`**

**`Spark-scala-1.6:`**

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

//sample data

val df=sc.parallelize(Seq(("2019-10-17'T'18:30:45.123"),("2019-10-15'T'18:30:45.123"))).toDF("ts")

df.filter(regexp_replace('ts,"'T'"," ").cast("timestamp") > current_timestamp).show(false)
```

**`Result:`**

```
+-------------------------+
|ts                       |
+-------------------------+
|2019-10-17'T'18:30:45.123|
+-------------------------+
```

In case if you need to replace `'T'` to get timestamp type for ts field then use this approach.

```
df.withColumn("ts",regexp_replace('ts,"'T'"," ").cast("timestamp"))
  .filter('ts > current_timestamp).show(false)
```

**`Result:`**

```
+-----------------------+
|ts                     |
+-----------------------+
|2019-10-17 18:30:45.123|
+-----------------------+
```

Result `ts` field will be having `Timestamp` type.